# real analysis bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

in Stein Shakarchi's Real Analysis they give a proof of the countable additivity of the Lebesgue measure, however they start the proof off by stating that it suffices to let the subsets $E_1,E_2... \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be bounded for each $j$?I was wondering why this condition is necessary, also can the proof be done without it? is it because if all subsets were unbounded then we could get infinite (Lebesgue) measure? EDIT: later on, they show the general case. So, I am good :)

Comment: Not necessary, as the conclusion is general. It’s just a convenience that makes the proof more readable.

Comment: thanks! I wonder would like would like like then without this assumption. Also does this assumption give me that in the next like he takes the complements to be less than epsilon / 2^j?

Comment: I am sorry I don’t know as I don’t have the book with me. It would help if you make the question self contained.